# ReactJS: Rewriting code from class to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I rewrote my code from class-based to function-based. Unfortunately, after rewriting it, I get the error message `TypeError: notes.map is not a function`.

```
const App = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [note, setNote] = useState("");
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
    const createNoteListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const newNote = noteData.value.data.onCreateNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const oldNotes = prevNotes.filter(note => note.id !== newNote.id);
          const updatedNotes = [...oldNotes, newNote];
          return updatedNotes;
        });
        setNote("");
      }
    });
    const deleteNoteListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onDeleteNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const deletedNote = noteData.value.data.onDeleteNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const updatedNotes = prevNotes.filter(
            note => note.id !== deletedNote.id
          );
          return updatedNotes;
        });
      }
    });
    const updateNoteListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onUpdateNote)
    ).subscribe({
      next: noteData => {
        const updatedNote = noteData.value.data.onUpdateNote;
        setNotes(prevNotes => {
          const index = prevNotes.findIndex(note => note.id === updatedNote.id);
          const updatedNotes = [
            ...notes.slice(0, index),
            updatedNote,
            ...notes.slice(index + 1)
          ];
          return updatedNotes;
        });
        setNote("");
        setId("");
      }
    });

    return () => {
      createNoteListener.unsubscribe();
      deleteNoteListener.unsubscribe();
      updateNoteListener.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const getNotes = async () => {
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listNotes));
    setNotes(result.data.listNotes.items);
  };

  const handleChangeNote = event => setNote(event.target.value);

  const hasExistingNote = () => {
    if (id) {
      const isNote = notes.findIndex(note => note.id === id) > -1;
      return isNote;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const handleAddNote = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Check if we have an exisiting note. If so, then update it.
    if (hasExistingNote()) {
      handleUpdateNote();
    } else {
      const input = { note };
      await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createNote, { input }));
    }
  };

  const handleUpdateNote = async () => {
    const input = { id, note };
    await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(updateNote, { input }));
  };

  const handleDeleteNote = async noteId => {
    const input = { id: noteId };
    await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteNote, { input }));
  };

  const handleSetNote = ({ note, id }) => {
    setNote(note);
    setId(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-column items-center justify-center pa3 bg-washed-red">
      <h1 className="code f2-l">Amplify Notetake</h1>
      {/* Note Form */}
      <form onSubmit={handleAddNote} className="mb3">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="pa2 f4"
          placeholder="Write your note"
          onChange={handleChangeNote}
          value={note}
        />
        <button className="pa2 f4" type="submit">
          {id ? "Update note" : "Add note"}
        </button>
      </form>

      {/* Notes list */}
      <div>
        {notes.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id} className="flex items-center">
            <li onClick={() => handleSetNote(item)} className="list pa1 f3">
              {item.note}
            </li>
            <button
              onClick={() => handleDeleteNote(item.id)}
              className="bg-transparent bn f4"
            >
              <span>&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(App, { includeGreetings: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

If `notes` is intended to be an array of notes as it appears to be, you'll want to initialize it with an empty array, so `const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);` instead of with an empty string like you currently are.

Comment: There actually still seems to be a problem I now see `Line 69:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'notes'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setNotes(n => ...)' if you only need 'notes' in the 'setNotes' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. After I changed it from `""` to `[]`. Do you see any other issue with my code?

Comment: At the end of `useEffect` you have this line: 
`}, []);` - you should either add `notes` to that array, or remove it altogether. If you pass that array in, you need to tell `useEffect` all state and properties that a change in them will cause the useEffect hook to fire.

Comment: Hmm in the course I made about it he said that's necessary so it is only used for the mount and unmount – not on all other effects.

Comment: That is what the empty array will do, yes. This is probably not an error and likely a warning? The react docs say there are better ways to do this but that it will work. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Ahh, in the very last minute he said he did a mistake and `...notes` should be `...prevNotes`.

Comment: [Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/) wrote [a comprehensive article on useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) which might help.

Answer (score 0):

Array in react hooks should be manipulated like this.

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems([
      ...items,
      {
        id: items.length,
        value: Math.random() * 100
      }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add a number</button>
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: After I changed `const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);` to `const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");`. There actually still seems to be a problem I now see `Line 69:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'notes'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setNotes(n => ...)' if you only need 'notes' in the 'setNotes' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. After I changed it from `""` to `[]`. Do you see any other issue with my code?

Answer (score 0):

try initializing notes state with []

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
```

see the following diff

[image]

Comment: In now see `Line 69:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'notes'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.` after I changed that. Do you have any other idea why?

Comment: this could be a linting warning